# Error in exposing an Entity with ODataService

Tags: odata, olingo

while I'm Passing an entity in the URL its saying ...
Could not find an entity set or function import for 'Books'.

I'm trying to expose an "ODataService" of book and publisher in Java. Code is very long. so can you suggest me what might be the possible cause for this??

Comment: Hello. Could you give us the version of Olingo you use? Thanks very much!

Comment: you can check with `$metadata` that the entity is properly defined or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you didn't define an entity set (`Books`) for an entity type (`Book` for example) within your EDM provider. To check this, you can have the look at the root URL of your service (for example `http://services.odata.org/V4/OData/OData.svc/`). I think that, in your case, no collection entry is defined for `Books` :

```
<service xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2007/app"  
         xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"  
         xmlns:m="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/metadata" 
         xml:base="http://services.odata.org/V4/OData/OData.svc/"  
         m:context="http://services.odata.org/V4/OData/OData.svc/$metadata">
    <workspace>
        <atom:title type="text">Default</atom:title>
        <collection href="Books">
            <atom:title type="text">Books</atom:title>
        </collection>
        (...)
    </workspace>
</service>
```

You could also check if an entity type is defined of type `Book`. See a link like that `http://services.odata.org/V4/OData/OData.svc/$metadata`.

```
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx" 
           Version="4.0">
    <edmx:DataServices>
        <Schema xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm" 
                Namespace="ODataDemo">
            <EntityType Name="Book">
            (...)
            </EntityType>
        </Schema>
    </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

The following link provides you a comprehensive description of how to implement an OData service with Olingo v4:

https://templth.wordpress.com/2015/04/27/implementing-an-odata-service-with-olingo/

See section "Implementing a custom EdmProvider" to see how to implement an EDM provider with Olingo.

Hope it will help you,
Thierry